# "Is there anything we could have done better?" auf Deutsch

Tags: english-to-german

Eine typische "follow-up" Frage an eine Kunde nach einer Bestellung: *"Is there anything we could have done better?"*

Der Google Übersetzer empfehlt:

> Gibt es etwas, das wir besser hätten machen können?

aber meine Intuition glaubt ihm nicht. Was mir in der Satz nicht gefällt:

1. Die Ordnung der Verben. Ich würde vermuten: *"...was wir besser machen können hätten"*. Das Verb "machen" würde ich in meinem Satz auf der erste Stelle stehen lassen. Auf jeden Fall.
2. Ich würde gerne das Verb "hätten" im Prinzip weglassen und würde stattdessen "könnten" benutzen, z.B. *"...das wir besser machen könnten?"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Is there anything we could have done better?*

> Hätten wir (irgend)etwas besser machen können?

Manchmal ist Deutsch doch kürzer und prägnanter als Englisch.

Answer (score 2):

In ordentlichem Standard-Schriftdeutsch kann man sagen:

> Was hätten wir besser machen können?
>
> Gibt es etwas, das wir besser machen können hätten?

Möglich - aber vielleicht eher in mündlicher Sprache auftretend - ist auch:

> Gibt es etwas, das wir hätten besser machen können?

Auch der Satz aus der von Dir benützten Übersetzungsmaschine

> Gibt es etwas, das wir **besser** hätten machen können?

wäre in mündlichem Deutsch - mit der entsprechenden Betonung - akzeptabel oder würde jedenfalls weitgehend unbemerkt den Redefluß hinunterschwimmen. Jedoch sehe ich eine gewisse Gefahr, dass er verstanden wird als

> Gibt es etwas, das wir besser hätten **machen** können.

wobei der Sinn sich verschiebt zu: "Gibt es etwas, das wir besser gemacht hätten, anstatt es zu lassen." Dies kommt daher, dass die Stellung am Satzende dem *machen* besonderes Gewicht gibt. Aber solange man immer schön das *besser* betont, ist die Gefahr gebannt.

Zur zweiten Frage: Ja, man kann gut (und einfacher) auch sagen:

> Was könnten wir besser machen?
>
> Gibt es etwas, das wir besser machen können/könnten?

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Erklärung! Übrigens, wohne ich auch in Hannover, wo man am saubersten Deutsch spricht :)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown   ...wobei mich nach wie vor irritiert, dass die hiesigen Leute in ihrem angeblich so reinen Deutsch ihre Stadt "Hannoofa" nennen.

Comment: Na ja, Du hast Recht! :) "Milano" nennen die auch "Mailand" LOL